# Subscribe multiple topics using fuzzy string matching?

Tags: ros, ros2, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, let's say I want to subscribe multiple topics in one node. All the topics are named with same prefix, such as `"/prefix_topic_a","/prefix_topic_b","/prefix_topic_c"`...

**Since the amount is not fixed, a hard-coding of subscription topic cannot be used.**
Is there anyway to find all topics with a certain prefix and automatically create subscribers for each topic? maybe using fuzzy string matching? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366531/subscribe-multiple-topics-using-fuzzy-string-matching?/) by [runtao](https://answers.ros.org/users/60564/runtao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was interesting to me to check it out: https://answers.ros.org/question/206893/getting-list-of-published-topics-from-within-c-code/
You can get a list of topics from the C++ code, as shown in
If you can get the topics, you'll be able to make partial matches or create a subscriber from them.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [runtao](https://answers.ros.org/users/60564/runtao/) on 2020-11-28**:
@miura, thanks, but it uses the master node in ROS1, which ROS2 dosen't have. How could the functionality be used in ROS2?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-28**:
For ROS2, it seems that get_topic_names_and_types can be used.

You can also use get_topic_names_and_types in ROS2. http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1node__interfaces_1_1_node_graph.html#a8389b748a52ef6280f5ac124ef153260